# Java Reflection getDeclaredMethod() with Class Types

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to understand Java reflecton and am encountering difficulties when working with non-Integer setter methods.

As an example, how can I resolve the "getDeclaredMethod()" call below?

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Target {
    String value;

    public Target() { this.value = new String("."); }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
    public String getValue() { return this.value; }
}

class ReflectionTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Class myTarget = Class.forName("Target");

            Method myMethod;
            myMethod = myTarget.getDeclaredMethod("getValue");  // Works!
            System.out.println("Method Name: " + myMethod.toString());

            Class params[] = new Class[1];
            //params[0] = String.TYPE; // ?? What is the appropriate Class TYPE?
            myMethod = myTarget.getDeclaredMethod("setValue", params); // ? Help ?
            System.out.println("Method Name: " + myMethod.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One Question I have for you, in what scenario, I will try to know which methods are in the class and Variables? why I will try to know that? I am exploring the reasons for using this methods getDeclaredMethod(), getDeclaredFields() , etc... Can you please suggest

Comment: One (random) reason for using reflection is if you want  to build a Json serialization/deserialization library. The well known Google Gson library heavily use reflections to achieve his tasks.

Examples of such usages can continue forever. You can for example build a network protocol you can use to serialize and send various Java objects properties to another application or to a server based on another language saving a huge amount of time for not having to implement a serialize method for all the classes you want exchange.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
params[0] = String.class;
```

Using `class` on `String` will return the `Class<?>` that is associated with the `String` class.

Comment: (Oops, I didn't mean to upvote the comment!)
I just wanted to add that I wasn't aware of it to the other day, so it's not exactly that obvious.

Comment: One Question I have for you, in what scenario, I will try to know which methods are in the class and Variables? why I will try to know that? I am exploring the reasons for using this methods getDeclaredMethod(), getDeclaredFields() , etc... Can you please suggest