# Proper way to check Java Reflection Calls?

Tags: java, reflection

I posted [a question last night](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891071/java-reflection-getdeclaredmethod-with-class-types) about Java Reflection and am discovering compiler warnings this morning.

```
C:\javasandbox\reflection>javac ReflectionTest.java
Note: ReflectionTest.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

C:\javasandbox\reflection>javac -Xlint:unchecked ReflectionTest.java
ReflectionTest.java:17: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to
getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<?>...) as a member of the raw
type java.lang.Class

        myMethod = myTarget.getDeclaredMethod("getValue");
                                             ^
ReflectionTest.java:22: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to
getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<?>...) as a member of the raw
type java.lang.Class

        myMethod = myTarget.getDeclaredMethod("setValue", params);
                                             ^
2 warnings
```

Is there a "proper" way to check these returned methods? (i.e. Is there a proper way to get rid of these warnings?)

Source code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Target {
    String value;

    public Target() { this.value = new String("."); }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
    public String getValue() { return this.value; }
}

class ReflectionTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Class myTarget = Class.forName("Target");

            Method myMethod;
            myMethod = myTarget.getDeclaredMethod("getValue");
            System.out.println("Method Name: " + myMethod.toString());

            Class params[] = new Class[1];
            params[0] = String.class;
            myMethod = myTarget.getDeclaredMethod("setValue", params);
            System.out.println("Method Name: " + myMethod.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Change

```
Class myTarget = Class.forName("Target");
```

to

```
Class<?> myTarget = Class.forName("Target");
```

That basically means, "I know it's generic, but I know nothing about the type argument." They're semantically equivalent, but the compiler can tell the difference. For more information, see the [relevant Java Generics FAQ entry](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html) ("What is the difference between the unbounded wildcard instantiation and the raw type?").

Comment: I believe the current JDK7 compiler will give a rawtypes warning on that line, as well as the deferred unchecked warning where the variable is used.

Comment: Do you mean on the first version? Presumably the second version is still okay.

Comment: Yes, the current JDK8 compiler gives a `raw types` error on the first line `Class`, but is happy with the second line `Class<?>`.